# Unwanted vertical align when table height is defined

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am creating a website using HTML and CSS. I have an HTML table where I am defining both the height and the width. I am defining the height (450px) so that the height is the same on every page throughout the site. However, when I define a height, everything within that table wants to be centered vertically. I have found lots of information on vertical alignment (how to), but trying to use those methods to undo the vertical alignment isn't working. Since removing the height is the only thing that undoes my problem, I am looking for a solution that allows me to specify my height but not vertically align everything in the table. I'll post code if necessary, but I think this question may not need it. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide code sample.

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle, preferably. :)

Comment: You need to provide a lot better explanation and/or a code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Without further information how about globally defining a td to vetical-align top? Below is for a page, but you can define this in a common css file that all your pages use to share the effect.

```
<html>
 <style>
  td {
   vertical-align:top;
  }
 </style>
 <body>
   <table style="height:450px;" border=1>
    <tr><td>hey</td><td>ho</td><td>let's go</td></tr>
    <tr><td>hey</td><td>ho</td><td>let's go</td></tr>
    <tr><td>hey</td><td>ho</td><td>let's go</td></tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If table in your code is used for layout purposes (not for marking-up tably *data*), I would recommend to use more modern CSS layout methods in conjunction with `min-height` for main container. For example, [negative-margins method](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/negativemargins/).